# .htaccess remove file extension before hashtag

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

http://freddygonzalez.me/dev/update/index.html#mywork.html

How can I use .htaccess to remove the index.html

So it could look like this
http://freddygonzalez.me/dev/update/#mywork.html

Also there may be one conflict.If the user press on the logo they get this
http://freddygonzalez.me/dev/update/index.html#index.html

So is there a way to use.htaccess to always remove the index.html but not the hashtag?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt it's possible, since the hash value is not passed to the server, it's used only by the browser so a redirect would drop it, but let's wait and see if someone comes up with an answer (a js redirect would do it tho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as per jadew's comment, if the hash makes it to the server this should match it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(dev/update/)index\.html(#.+\.html)$ $1$2 [L]
```

Comment: Well that answers the hash question.

Answer (score 2):

The fragment of a URL is not sent to the server, it’s meant for local usage only:

> […] the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
>      processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
>      from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
>      identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
>      solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme.

So there is no way to remove it from a request with mod_rewrite since the server doesn’t know anything about the fragment.

But the client obviously does know. So you can use some client side techniques like JavaScript to remove or adjust the fragment.